# Stop Kotlin flow on certain return value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am new with Kotlin Flow. I want to execute a few function, one by one and stop execution if any of error. I am using the following code for the that:

```
fun uploadProjectData(contactId: String, projectId: String) = flow<Resource<Boolean>> {
        emit(test1(contactId, projectId))
        emit(test2(contactId, projectId))
        emit(test3(contactId, projectId))
    }.onEach {
        if (it.errorCode != 0) {
            return@onEach
        }
        delay(0)
    }.flowOn(
        Dispatchers.IO
    )

    suspend fun test1(contactId: String, projectId: String): Resource<Boolean> {
        // api call or DB operation
        return responseHandler.handleSuccess(true, "test1 Successful")
    }
     
    suspend fun test2(contactId: String, projectId: String): Resource<Boolean> {
        // api call or DB operation
        return responseHandler.handleError(999, "test2 Unsuccessful")
    }

    suspend fun test3(contactId: String, projectId: String): Resource<Boolean> {
        // api call or DB operation
        return responseHandler.handleSuccess(true, "test2 Successful")
    }
```

Although test2() returning 999 error code, the execution does not stop, it also execute test3(). What is the problem in this code? How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe you want to use [takeWhile](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/take-while.html)

Comment: It is working. Thanks.

Comment: Neo, could you please add your comment as an answer? I was going to ask similar question but this question appeared in suggestions without answer but in fact it had an answer. It may be useful, thanks.